# Error while running opencv

Tags: python, opencv

While running cv2 version 2.4.9 in Ubuntu 12.04, i got an error that is

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZNK14QWidgetPrivate17hasHeightForWidthEv`

I am attaching the image below, please help me to how to solve this issue.
[image]

Comment: How did you install opencv?

Comment: Are you sure that you have correctly installed opencv